# Delete Objects of localStorage after AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, local-storage

**//    Edit**

Thanks for all the help so far. I'm afraid, I did pretty much wrong, so I re-structured the whole code als also the "structure" of the localStorage Array

Here's my full code and the intention behind it. I want to check for connectivity (*for which I use pingjs.js*) and if there's no connectivity, the user input gets stored in the localStorage. If we get a ping back, we upload everything in the localStorage through jQuery AJAX and **delete this submitted data** (not everything which came after, for example) from the localStorage Array. The thing is also, that I want to avoid duplicates (update already existing data **based on stnr AND pstn**) and also get something like a **unique id for indexing the localStorage Array**.

So far this is my code with exception of the indizes and the updating of already existing stnr AND pstn:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pingjs.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#store').click(function() {
            var startnummer = $("#startnummer").val();
            var ergebnis = $("#ergebnis").val();
            var position = $("#position").val();

            var data = [
                {
                    "stnr": startnummer,
                    "rslt": ergebnis,
                    "pstn": position
                }
            ]

            /*  
                So far I use localStorage.length for indexing, but
                I want something for checking of duplicates and update
                them if necessary, based on stnr AND pstn, so if these
                are same, only update rslt
            */
            localStorage.setItem((localStorage.length), JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        //  We got a ping
        ping('https://example.com/').then(function(delta) {
            if(window.localStorage !== undefined) {
                var fields = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'xyz.php',
                    data: fields,
                    success: function(html){
                        //  Here I want to delete all the passed data
                        localStorage.removeItem( ??? );

                        //  Output status
                        $('#status').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500).html(html);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Storage Failed. Try refreshing");
            }   
        //  We have no ping
        }).catch(function(err) {
            alert('Could not ping remote URL', err);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The storing works without problems. So no problem here.

Comment: um, removeItem removes the localstoage by key, not sure how those lines apply to it. How is the stuff added to localstorage?

Comment: I've updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: `setItem()` updates the key if it already exists

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you may not understand localStorage API completely. I would suggest reading [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) from MDN.

The first problem is it seems like you may be storing the information in localStorage incorrectly. Local storage is **key based**. This means that all data is located in local storage via a key. For instance `{"key" : "data"}`.

A side note, data in local storage is kept as a string. So in order to `read/write` data `to/from` local storage you need to `stringify/parse` it.

To continue on your question, I am under the impression you are saving that entire array in localStorage, and then trying to remove each key inside of the array. As stated before, this wont work, for a few reasons. Firstly, you cannot use the `localStorage.removeItem()` method to remove an object stored because the object is actually a string and not parsed. Secondly, even if it wasn't saved as a string, the function doesn't operate on the storage data, but on the key the data was stored under. What your code is missing, which would help greatly, is the way you are saving in `localStorage` in the first place. Because in this case you would not even have to call `removeItem()` three times, just call it once on the key it's all stored under. Let me give an example I think may relate to your question:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "Joe"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Peter"
  }
]

//Setting the data to localStorage under the key "people"
localStorage.setItem("people", data);

// ... inside your ajax function
 ...({

  //Remove whole array of data based on key

  localStorage.removeItem("people");
  
  //All done with removal
  
  //Rest of your code
 })
```

**IF** you would like the delete just those specific keys in `localStorage`, you're going to either have to save them separately (recommended), or you're going to have to read, parse, edit, resave (not recommended) the data every time you want to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I'm a bit confused now, since my array has the same structure as yours. For example: I want to delete Joe from your array, so how am I doing that? I already read about localStorage and the example I posted was all I learned from the websites.

Comment: You have to read the array into a variable with `localStorage.getItem()`, remove the object in the array by its key, and then `localStorage.setItem()` again. This might help: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/07/16/removing-elements-from-javascript-arrays. The other option is save each object in localStorage under its own key. So `localStorage.setItem("stnr", tmemberDataObject.stnr)`

Answer (score 0):

Call `removeItem` function passing the key of the data you want to remove.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'xyz.php',
    data: {
        results: resultobj
    },
    success: function(callback){
        // Delete data from staticLS here
        localStorage.removeItem("tmemberData")
        // Output message of callback status
        $('#status').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500).html(callback);
    }
});
```

Comment: But doesn't that delete the whole "tmemberData"? I just want to delete the key values passed to ajax

Comment: In your ajax request you are sending `resultobj` and that object is `JSON.stringify(tmemberDataObject)` beign `tmemberDataObject` what you get from localStorage

Comment: Just tried your code and noticed that it "clears" the whole tmemberDataObject but when I'm adding new values, the old ones appear again with the newly one added. Furthermore I just want to delete the "values" passed to my xyz.php. Not the whole tmemberDataObject